# Arredondar minutos C#

Tags: c#

Pessoal estou com um problema que é o seguinte, preciso arredondar os minutos de uma hora, por exemplo: se a hora for 12:28 preciso que ela vire 12:30, preciso arredondar sempre para maior, alguém sabe como resolver isto? Lembrando que estou trabalhando com TimeSpan. Se alguém conseguir me ajudar eu agradeço.

Comment: dá uma olhada [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499479/how-to-round-off-hours-based-on-minuteshours0-if-min30-hours1-otherwise?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), acho que resolve.

Comment: Sempre para o maior? 12:21 vira 12:30 ou 12:20?

Comment: Isso sempre para maior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Voce pode fazer isso da seguinte forma:

```
public static class TempoUtils{
    private static int MultiploSeguinte(int n, int m){
        var resto = n % m;
        if(resto == 0) return n;
        var faltam = m - resto;
        return n + faltam;
    }

    public static TimeSpan CeilMinutos(this TimeSpan tempo, int multiplo){
        var multiploSeguinte = MultiploSeguinte(tempo.Minutes, multiplo);
        return new TimeSpan(tempo.Hours, multiploSeguinte, tempo.Seconds);
    }   

}

void Main()
{
    var tempo = new TimeSpan(12, 21, 00);
    tempo.CeilMinutos(30).Dump();
}
```

Há muita coisa a acontecer por isso vale uma explicação. A função `MultiploSeguinte` Calcula o próximo múltiplo (ou o próprio número caso ele seja um múltiplo) dum número consoante o parâmetro 'm'.

A função `CeilMinutos` usa `MultiploSeguinte` mas trabalha com a estrutura `TimeSpan` que é a estrutura que voce está interessado.

Eu fiz uso de métodos de extensao que lhe permitem aceder a metodos estáticos como se eles fossem métodos de instancia. Na prática isto permite-lhe chamar `tempo.CeilMinutos` em vez de  `TempoUtils.CeilMinutos(tempo, 30)`